# Transforming list of lists into pandas unable to separate columns

Tags: python

I'm trying to transform a list of lists into a pandas dataframe. This is the list:

```
[[array([[u'2017-08-22', u'xxx BRAZIL', u'channel_name1',
        u'SEM xx-xx', u'sessions', u'-0.413447782546', u'-1156',
        u'1640.0', u'2796.0']],
      dtype='<U32')], [array([[u'2017-08-22', u'xxx BRAZIL', u'channel_name1',
        u'xx-xx', u'sessions', u'0.0180327868852', u'11',
        u'621.0', u'610.0']],
      dtype='<U32')], [array([[u'2017-08-22', u'xxx BRAZIL', u'channel_name1',
        u'xx-xxx', u'sessions', u'-0.0529421060949',
        u'-1005', u'17978.0', u'18983.0']],
      dtype='<U32')], [array([[u'2017-08-22', u'xxx BRAZIL', u'channel_name1',
        u'xx-xx', u'sessions', u'-0.150395778364', u'-114',
        u'644.0', u'758.0']],
...
```

This is my code:

```
df = DataFrame(outliers_list)
```

But I'm getting this as output:

```
                                                   0
0  [[2017-08-22, XXX, channel_name1, RE...
1  [[2017-08-22, xxx, channel_name1, CR...
2  [[2017-08-22, xxx, channel_name1, DI...
3  [[2017-08-22, xxx, channel_name1, AF...
4  [[2017-08-22, xxx, channel_name1, RE...
5  [[2017-08-22, xxx, channel_name1, CR...
6  [[2017-08-22, xxx, channel_name1, DI...
7  [[2017-08-22, xxx, channel_name1, RE...
8  [[2017-08-22, xxx, channel_name1, CR...
9  [[2017-08-22, xxx, channel_name1, DI...
```

I'm getting entire row into only one column. How can I separate the columns?

Comment: Not sure it's useful, but you can split by commas: http://dpaste.com/08J2PKB

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([a[0][0] for a in outliers_list])
```